# how to display an Arima prédiction in Tableau

Tags: r

I want to integrate Tableau desktop with R in orther to display a graph appended to its Arima prediction.To do so, I created a calculated field in Tableau for the shifted date to display it in the X-axis.This is the code:

```
` IFNULL(LOOKUP(ATTR([Day]), [Période To Forecast]),ATTR(DATEADD('day',[Période To Forecast], [Day])))`
```

I then created another calculated field to display to display it in the Y axis:

```
`SCRIPT_REAL("library(forecast);
 myts <- ts(.arg1)
 arimafit <- auto.arima(myts);
 fcast <- forecast(arimafit, .arg2[1]);
 n<-length(.arg1);
 append(.arg1,fcast$mean, after = n)",
 Sum([Nb Visiteurs Uniques]),[Période To Forecast])`
```

I received an error in Tableau telling me that:"la fonction script a renvoyé un nombre de résultats inattendus.
I tried then to reduce the number of points, so I changed the content of the append function like that:

```
`append(.arg1[(.arg2[1]+1):n],fcast$mean, after = n-.arg2[1])",`
```

I received this error: Error in x[1L:after] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
I searched in the net and understood that there is a negative term in the .arg1 variable.But the number I'm displaying is positive.Does R interprete the number as being negative?

Comment: are there any suggestions please ?